# How to Pause my Game View Controler (game) when segue to another VIew Controler (which is menu)

Tags: model-view-controller, sprite-kit, pause

How to Pause my Game View Controler (which is the game) when segue to another VIew Controler (which is menu) , so When I press resume button in Menu View Controler it goes back to the Game View Controler right where it left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `paused` property of your scene to true. Put this in your `prepareForSegue`.

```
gameScene.paused = true //gameScene is whatever your scene variable is
```

When you return to the game VC, just set `paused` to false.

If you look at the docs for SKScene you'll notice its a subclass of SKNode. [Here's a link to the paused property on SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/paused)

Comment: I am doing the segue thru the Main.storyboard, I just added a button (pause) which segue to anothor view Controler (menu) ... how can I pause that if its thru Main.storyboad ?

Comment: Set a storyboard id for the segue. in your view controller's `prepareForSegue`, you can check the identifier of the segue. In this way you can know in code if the triggered segue is the one you created in your storyboard. Regardless of whether you created your segue in code or interface builder, your view controller will call `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! One more quiestion... how can a kill (close) my Menu View Controler after I press Resume Button in it (sow it shows my Game View Controler again (which is supposed to be paussed now) ?

Comment: I actually did self.view.hidden = true when I press resume button, but then I have a black screen instead of the game...

Comment: There's a function - `dismissViewController`. Call it on self (the menu vc) when the menu exit button is tapped. That should help you out!

Comment: Thanks man, but do you know why my game (game view controler) gets black screen after I call menu (menu view control) ? its like something its killing the first view controler wich is in backround....